# Python standard library not working inside virtualenv

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Here are the contents of `re.py`:

```
import re
if re.search('test', 'test'): print 'match'
```

When I run `$ python re.py`, the output, obviously, is `match`. But when I activate a virtualenv and try to run the script again, I get:

```
...
    if re.search('test', 'test'): print 'match'
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Here's the output of the Python interpreter when the virtualenv is not active:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun  3 2013, 17:42:22)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57))] on darwin
```

And here's the output when it's active:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
```

Why does the `re` module break when using Python 2.7.5 inside the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `re` internal module and `re.py` your module mixed.

Please change your file name to `re_example.py` and try.

Comment: That worked--thanks. But why does the virtualenv matter?

Comment: That I have to check, but never give file name as python inbuilt module.